# Symfony2, how to display data from entities with ManyToMany associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have multiple entities associated by ManyToMany and ManyToOne associations and I have problem with displaying data more than one level deep in to associations

For example. There are 3 entities connected. Customer->Address->Country. In TWIG I can display:

```
{{ customer.name }} // outputs name
{{ customer.address.postcode }} // outputs post code from Address entity
```

But this:

```
{{ customer.address.country.isocode2 }} //should output ISO code from country entity
```

Outputs 500 internal server error:

```
Method "isocode2" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in AppBundle:tables:customers.html.twig at line 43
```

More info
Customer entity, address mapping

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Address
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="defaultaddress_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $address;
```

Country mapping in address entity

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="address_country",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $country;
```

Country entity:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isocode2", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $isocode2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isocode3", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $isocode3;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="country")
 */
private $address;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

If I try to do this

```
{{ customer.address.country }}
```

I am getting

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string in app/cache/dev/twig/1d/7c/3eec624c629866dcd530ea084487b111c573dbcba579efa7a6b315c46c7a.php line 120
```

Comment: Provide your mappings for entities

Comment: You can transfere the isocodes via the Controller when you generate the twig even if it's a bad practice. Could you join a [dump] (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) of "customer" ?

Comment: The error message indicates that country is an array which seems strange.  Check your mapping between address and country or post your address mappings.

Comment: I've added more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ManyToMany association, an Address can have multiple countries. Is this correct for your logic?

If it is, you have to iterate on all countries of Address:

```
{% for country in customer.address.country %}
    {{ country.isocode2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

If your address have only one country, you must use ManyToOne association. Then you can use your syntax:

```
{{ customer.address.country.isocode2 }}
```

Comment: You are correct sir. I've manage to set it up correctly but for some reason php app/console doctrine:schema:update is trying to create unique key in database on customer.address

Comment: Sometimes it's a problem about MySQL index. If you are in development, try dropping database and re-creating it.

Comment: I figure this out. The key was generated because of the code in entity. I've generated entities from database scheme and it moved key to the entity so when I was trying to update db from entity it was generating also that key. Stupid mistake.